# Validation logic for range check with input can be String or Number

Tags: java, validation

**Requirement**

Validate two inputs (from and to).  Input can be either `Number` or `String` (value hast to be date in UTC format)
"from" and "to" both cannot be empty or null but one of them can be empty or null.

Pre condition : Use only Java 7

My simplest validation logic. Please let me know if I can optimize this code.
Ignore JSONException part.

```
private static void validate(Object from, Object to) throws JSONException {
    if ((from == null && to == null)
            || (isEmpty(from) && isEmpty(to))) {
        throw new JSONException("\"from\" or \"to\" has to be specified in range filter");
    }
    if (!isEmpty(from)) {
        validateRange(from);
    }
    if (!isEmpty(to)) {
        validateRange(to);
    }
}

private static void validateRange(Object range) throws JSONException {
    //Valid date
    if (range instanceof String) {
        String input = (String) range;
        //Empty check 
        if (!input.matches("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z$")) {
            throw new JSONException("range check field is not a valid date");
        }
    }
}
private static boolean isEmpty(Object range) throws JSONException{
    //Instance check
    if (!(range instanceof Number) || !(range instanceof String)) {
        throw new JSONException("From and To in range can be only of type Date or Integer");
    }

    if (range instanceof String) {
        return ((String) range).trim().isEmpty();
    } else {
        return true; //For Number this check always true.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yes true. I was modifying the question based on my unit tests not based on the answer provided below. There were logic flows which I found while running through my unit tests

Comment: I'd recommend taking both the advice of the answer and the found flaws to write a new version of your code and post this as a new question. This is called a follow-up. Feel free to link back to this question for bonus context. While you're at it, please take a look at [how-to-ask](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) to make your next question an above-average one. Those tend to get more exposure, more upvotes and more/better answers.

Comment: Thanks Mast . I will go through the link and improve the questions for the next post.

Answer (score 3):

#### Possible bug

```
if (!(range instanceof Number) || !(range instanceof String)) {
    throw new JSONException("From and To in range can be only of type Date or Integer");
}
```

Does it even work?? It throws an exception if `range` is *either* not a Number, **or** not a String. But it's inevitable, because if it's a String, then it can't be a Number, and vice versa. Didn't you mean `&&`?

#### Communicating validation failure

Why does validation failure result in a `JSONException` (of all exceptions)? I can't see how `range` object not being a `Number` is a JSON issue?

Besides, using exceptions to communicate an error isn't something I would choose to do lightly. Exceptions are quite costly - they're quite a heavy-weight mechanism which rates very poorly as far as performance is concerned, *plus* it forces consuming code to wrap validation calls in clunky `try-catch` blocks even if all it wanted was just to check whether the value is correct.

A better alternative would be to return a `bool`, or some sort of an error object (containing additional info about the input).

#### Contextual info

Furthermore, your exceptions aren't informative. They only tell me what criteria the value failed to meet, but not why. *"range check field is not a valid date"* - what is it, then? Understanding a possible bug or malfunction is much easier if the actual, unexpected value is quoted in error logs.

```
if (!(range instanceof Number) || !(range instanceof String)) {
    throw new JSONException("From and To in range can be only of type Date or Integer");
}
```

Apart from the condition looking doubtful to me (as explained in the first paragraph), this exception message is not true - your input is checked for being of `String` type, not `Date` type.

#### Code style

```
if (range instanceof String) {
    return ((String) range).trim().isEmpty();
} else {
    return true;
}
```

`else` after a `return` is redundant. This whole expression could be simplified to:

```
return !(range instanceof String) || ((String) range).trim().isEmpty();
```

or at least

```
return range instanceof String
    ? ((String) range).trim().isEmpty()
    : true;
```

Note that depending on the platform and libraries you are using, the `trim().isEmpty()` bit could possibly be replaced by an utility method call. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819800/whats-the-better-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-empty-than-using-string-trim-len for suggestions (although they may not apply in your case).

#### Comments

```
//Instance check
if (!(range instanceof Number) || !(range instanceof String)) {
```

I suggest that you get rid of this "instance check" comment, as it explains the obvious and doesn't add any value to your code.

```
//Empty check 
if (!input.matches("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z$")) {
```

And this comment is simply untrue. The condition doesn't only fail if input is empty - it fails when it doesn't match your predefined data format.

#### Naming

```
private static void validateRange(Object range)
```

It doesn't validate the whole range (comprised of `from` and `to`). It only validates `from` or `to` on its own, which is called a **bound**.

```
private static boolean isEmpty(Object range) throws JSONException
```

I can accept a `validate` or `assert` method to throw an exception, but this one is called `isEmpty` - this name indicates it's a method I can use to calmly obtain some info about the object. And yet it performs both responsibilities at once - apart from providing info, it also validates the input in an aggressive manner (throwing an exception). This violates the principle of least surprise in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I agree with some of the points .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my implementation. I agree with Konrad regarding the throwing a error message instead of constructing exception everywhere but I choose to not do it mainly due to code clarity.

```
   private static void validate(Object from, Object to) throws JSONException {
    instanceCheck(to);
    instanceCheck(from);

    if ((from == null && to == null)
            || (isEmpty(from) && isEmpty(to))
            || (from == null && isEmpty(to))
            || (to == null && isEmpty(from))) {
        throw new JSONException("\"from\" or \"to\" has to be specified in range filter");
    }
    if (!isEmpty(from)) {
        validateDate(from);
    }
    if (!isEmpty(to)) {
        validateDate(to);
    }
}

private static void instanceCheck(Object range) throws JSONException {
    if (range != null
            && !(range instanceof Number)
            && !(range instanceof String)) {
        throw new JSONException("\"from\" and \"to\" in range can be only of type Date or Number");
    }
}

private static boolean isEmpty(Object range) throws JSONException {

    return (range instanceof String)
            ? ((String) range).trim().isEmpty() : Boolean.FALSE;

}

private static void validateDate(Object date) throws JSONException {
    //Valid date
    if (date instanceof String) {
        String input = (String) date;
        //Empty check 
        if (!input.matches("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z$")) {
            throw new JSONException("Not a valid date");
        }
    }
}
```